# Analyzing the time complexity of an algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, time-complexity, big-o

I was asked in an interview to write a function which, given a tree and two nodes in the tree, returns the closest ancestor to both those children.

Here is my code:

```
two_paths = []

def get_closest_ancestor(path1, path2):

    for i in xrange(min(len(path1), len(path2))):
        if path1[i] != path2[i]:
            return path1[i-1]

def find_two_paths(root, a, b, path = []):
    global two_paths

    newpath = path[:]

    newpath.append(root)

    if len(two_nodes) == 2:
        return

    if root == a:
        two_paths.append(newpath)
    if root == b:
        two_paths.append(newpath)

    for child in root.children:
        find_two_paths(child, a, b, newpath)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    find_two_paths(root, a, b)
    print get_closest_ancestor(two_paths)
```

I was then asked to give the Big O Complexity of the algorithm I just wrote.

So we have 2 function, `find_two_paths`, and `get_closest_ancestor`.

My first question, is, what are we taking as an input here. What is `n` in our Big O notation?

I figured we were looking at the depth of the tree as `n`

`find_two_paths` obviously performs a DFS search, so we already have exponential time complexity, I think.

Can we use the fact that it is a tree, and say that the complexity is `O(b^n)` where `b` is the branching factor of the tree, and `n` is the depth?

Can we just say it is `O(2^n)`?

Can we ignore the `get_closest_ancestor` function because it is `O(n)` and is heavily overpowered by `find_two_paths`?

Comment: I'd say the size of the tree (number of nodes) is a suitable metric for `n`.

Comment: You just have to search for common entries in the the two paths to the root. So it should O(log n)

Comment: We are only given the root of the tree as an input and cant access the parent of the nodes `a` and `b`

Comment: You probably know this, but code as written doesn't work (`two_paths` is never written to, use of mutable default param--ew--, you should've called with `*two_paths`)

Comment: Sorry, in the interview I  did this: `path[:]`, `two_nodes` should be `two_paths`, sorry, I typed this up on SO quickly, should have proof-read.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: You'd need to declare `two_paths` as global for that to work. DFS is not exponential time. It's proportional to the number of nodes. You have to DFS to find the paths to the two (which you did) in `O(n)` and then you have to traverse up to `log(n)` of the two paths (not technically correct I guess, because it isn't a balanced binary tree, could be as worse as n I guess, but that doesn't effect the overall). So overall this is `O(n)`.

Comment: Of course, thank you !

Comment: @BaileyParker Why not make that an answer?

Comment: "We are only given the root of the tree as an input...": this belongs to the question and should be stated there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is definitely not `O(2^n)`. It's much faster. For graph problems, it's typical to define the `n` to be number of nodes in the tree. So let's summarize what your algorithm does:

1. DFS from root to find a then b (remembering the paths to them)
2. Comparing those paths item by item until it finds a discrepancy (and returns the last common node)

For step 1, [DFS is `O(n)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search). You visit every node once so your performance is proportional to the number of nodes. One thing of note here is you do actually short circuit (albeit by the use of a global) so you don't consider all nodes. Of course, the worst case is that `a` and `b` are the two last nodes we visit and thus the DFS would be `O(n)`.

For step 2, the worst case is that the paths are same up until the last node (`a` and `b` are siblings). So the worst performance of this will be proportional to the length of the longest possible list. Now, we can think critically about step 1 and deduce that the O(n) from visiting every node will always be larger than or equal to the longest path we can have in step 2 (so overall the `O(n)` will dominate and it will be `O(n)` time), but let's be thorough. If we had some guarantees about the tree (such that it was a balanced binary tree), we could say the longest path was `O(log n)` and thus comparing the two paths would be at worst `O(log n)`. However we don't have such a guarantee. We could say more generally that if we could approximate the branching factor of the graph (average number of children each node has) to be `b` then we could approximately say that the longest path would be `O(log_b n)`. But for a general tree (worst case is a linked list), the path is O(n) length. Thus, step 2 is also worst case O(n).

Thus the overall runtime of this `O(n)`.

Comment: "it's typical to define the n to be number of nodes visited": with such a definition, searching a binary search tree would be O(n) ! You probably mean the total number of nodes in the tree ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Tree metric complexity is usually the number of nodes. There is a lack of assumptions to answer precisely especially concerning order of nodes in the tree. A simple general solution would be to construct path1 from node1 to the root, and then construct path2 from node2 to the root while verifying at each step if the current node is or not in path1. Of course if your tree is an ordered one some optimisations are obviously possible.

Say your tree of *n* nodes has exact degree *d*, then constructing path1 requires *log_d(n)* steps at worst, constructing path2 also requires *log_d(n)* steps at worst but for each of its steps you need to search into path1 which takes *log_d(n)*. Then at the end it takes *log_d(n)^2*.